# finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1 , error: Webflux, Webclient, Spring boot, java

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, webclient, spring-webflux

I'm having this error while using webclient in localhost, can you help me guys ??

```
ERROR                  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler - [0e1ef5cd-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP G
ET "/product/spec/template/posts"
product      | io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8090
product      |  Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
product      | Error has been observed at the following site(s):
product      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://localhost:8090/retailer/retailer/posts/12 [DefaultWebClient]
product      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.zucco.tech.hm.service.product.controller.ProductSpecTemplateController#posts() [DispatcherHandler]
product      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
product      |  |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/product/spec/template/posts" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
product      | Stack trace:
product      | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
product      |  at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124) ~[netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.51.Final.jar!/:4.1.51.Final]
```

Comment: Check if you have anything running on 127.0.0.1:8090. Use `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 8090`

Answer (score 3):

No, we can not call direct by localhost, the term here is "container call container", so, we should call together by container name.

1. change the docker-compose like this:

> ```
> order-service:
>   build: docker/order-service
>   container_name: order-service
>   ports:
>     - 8082:8080
> ```

2. And then, in the client service, we just define host like below:

> private String hostname =
> "http://order-service:8080/order-service/welcome";

You can see, when we call order service by browser (real client), we call throught extend port (8082), but in case container call container, we should call by it`s container`s name and it`s port (8080).

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused means that there was no server listening on the address:port. You can check with `netstat -tulpen` what ports are open on which address.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, while running my application, but I found out that the issue was that I had two micro-services that were having the same name in the application.yml.
Kindly confirm that all the micro-services you have defined have unique name and ports.